# Passing queried result to another node.js page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, database

I have two javascript files,
main.js:- one that does database queries and stores result in "rows"
samp.js:- one that calls main.js
My problem is, How do i pass the "rows" from main.js to samp.js, Tried module.exports,prototypes, but to no avail, I know this is a simple problem, but these kind of simple problems don't have documentation and it's difficult to solve it without help,

main.js:

```
var mysql=require('mysql');
var row1;
function person(){}
var con=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password:'',
    database:'imd2'
});
con.connect();

person.prototype.getdata= function(callback)
{
    con.query("select * from users",function(err,rows)
    {
        //row1=rows;
        console.log(rows);
        //return(rows);
}
);
}
module.exports=person;
```

here "console.log(rows)" work, but when i try to return it to samp.js, it does not work

Samp.js

```
var person=require("./main");

var person1=new person();

person1.getdata()
//var x=person1.getdata()
//console.log(x)
```

Can you tell me where's the mistake I made, every stackoverflow question i've searched doesn't have function-ed variables passed to other file, please help

Comment: Use `callback(row)` and call `person1.getdata(function(data){ console.log(data);  })`

Comment: @MukeshSharma `person1.getdata(console.log);` is shorter :). Not sure it fixes anything tho.

Comment: Yup @PierreC. thanks (y)

Comment: Do you have any error showing up? I made a little test on my computer and your code seems to be fine. I didn't made any request to a database tho.

Comment: @PierreC. no error, just the asynchronous call of query is giving me the problem of returning data

Comment: Oh I miss understood the question I guess. Your problem is with asynchronous methods. You need to call the callback with row as a parameter like @MukeshSharma pointed out. I'll make an answer.

Comment: @MukeshSharma thank you very much (y) i feel like you just solved a million dollar question!

Comment: Pleasure is mine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using and asynchronous method (`con.query`) like if it is synchronous. In asynchronous methods, you can not return the value using a return statement. You instead have to call a callback function.

In main.js:

```
person.prototype.getdata= function(callback)
{
    con.query("select * from users",function(err,rows)
    {
        callback(rows);
    });
}
```

In Samp.js:

```
person1.getdata(function(rows) {
    // use rows here
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Comment: I am going to award you with lots of stackoverflow questions which have the same problem as mine,
I want you to laugh at their answers and help the asker solve his question, because I just spent 48hrs without posting this question, I will like to thank u a gazzilion times because you just saved my job! literally!
P.S please upvote the question because i see a lot of indirect answer to this exact problem,

Comment: @VishwanthIronHeart Glad I could help ! Spend some time understanding asynchronous calls if you haven't already. It is not hard but you have to make it real clear in your mind.

Comment: I will, The thing is, I have this bizarre project details which require using alexa to act like an personal assistant, well this is the first step in solving it is to connect with a database(as with any project). Since the deadline is short, i'm just trying to learn what's needed at the present, and since asynchronous wasnt required before, i've stumbled upon this simple problem, I'm sure this was easy for you right? If i had the time to go through documentation, I wouldn't have had asked this question! Thanks anyway

Comment: I have another problem, relating to the order of execution of this same files, should i post a new question or will you help me here?